# I want to prevent a textbox to accept only alphabets

Tags: angular6

I am designing a membership form and want only alphabets is textbox as username.

ng-pattern="/^\d{1,10}$/" 
I tried it but it not works.

Comment: Please any one send me solution..

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you're using will only get digits

```
/^\d{1,10}$/"
```

- `\d{1,10}` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `{1,10}` Quantifier — Matches
  between 1 and 10 times, as many times as possible, giving back as
  needed
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line

If you want only alphanumeric characters try this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]*$
```

It will accept any character a through z -- capital or lower case.